User not visible with `who` and not logged in the `last`
This is related to this issue. Basically if I login with VSCode remote to the server, there will be no sign of that on the server side. My activity will not be under neither last|less nor who. I guess this is due to remote operating via SSH tunnel and not direct connection. This rases certain safety concerns in my company, which I understand even though use of VSC remote is convinient.
I don't think there's anything I can do, but I wish I was wrong. Being able to use VSCode editor directly with server files visible in the explorer, and having terminal open in the same window is convinient, but we just cannot skip over fact, that tracing user's activity on the server is limmited.
Is there anything we can do? Also, how safe is this SSH tunnel? As for now it looks like creating a backdoor.

I was also wondering this - any chance you found https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/1671 and tried the change there? It didn't work for me but I didn't put too much time into it and it's a stab in the dark.
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux": "bash",
"terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
"bash": {
"path": "bash",
"icon": "terminal-bash",
"args": ["--login"]
}
}

If your remote is a linux machine you can use:
ps -aux | grep vscode | awk '{ print $1 }' | sort -nu

On my ubuntu 22.04 LTS machine this generates the output:
$ ps -aux | grep vscode | awk '{ print $1 }' | sort -nu
bradley

when I'm logged in via via vscode remote explorer over SSH. Obviously, I have a bash session running to run the above command, but I've tested with some nohup'ery and verified that it will still show active vscode processes associated with the user remote'd in over the SSH tunnel, even if they're not running a bash session within VSCode.
A more generic approach to see users running processes on the remote might look something like this
(assuming that you don't care about users running processes with a pty attached)
$ uids=$(ps -eo pid,uid,args | awk '$2 >= 1000' | awk '{ print $2 }' | sort -nu | tail -n +2)
$ getent passwd $uids | awk -F  ':' '{ print $1 }'
bradley
john
alex

You can also use lsof, but that will require superuser access to show all users, I believe.
Related questions:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/617652/how-can-i-list-all-currently-logged-in-users
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/716267/determine-how-the-user-logged-in
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/4846

